# How to call class function in .map of React Native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am going to call function of class in template.
This is what I have done.

```
class recommendFeedback extends Component<{}>{
    starImgFromRating(tip) { // this function should be called but not.
    // ... some operation with tip.
        return result
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View style = {styles.container}>
                {
                    this.props.venue.tips.map(function(item) {
                        return <View>
                                    <Thumbnail source = {()=>this.starImgFromRating(item)} />
                                </View>
                    })
                }
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

But It doesn't work well.

Comment: Do you need to pass the result of `starImgFromRating()` into `source` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `source = {this.starImgFromRating(item)}` since you need to evaluate the result of `starImgFromRating` during rendering for the `Thumbnail` component to use.

Passing a function as a prop value is generally for event handlers.

You should also use the arrow function for `map`: `.map((item) => {` to avoid binding `this` to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **map** function as below:

```
            YOUR_ARRAY.map((value, index) => {
             })
```

Another Way is:

```
yourmethodName() {

    YOUR_ARRAY.map((data) => {
      return (
        <View><Text>{data}</Text></View>
      )
    })

}
```

You can call method like this

```
{this.yourmethodName()}
```